# Tensorflow RNN: how to infer a sequence without duplicates?

Tags: python, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network, sequence-to-sequence

I'm working on a seq2seq RNN generating an output sequence of labels given a seed label. During the inference step I'd like to generate sequences containing only unique labels (i.e. skip labels that have already been added to the output sequence). To do this I created a sampler object that tries to remember the labels that have been added to the output and reduce their logit value to `-np.inf`.

Here is the sampler code:

```
class InferenceSampler(object):
    def __init__(self, out_weights, out_biases):
        self._out_weights = tf.transpose(out_weights)
        self._out_biases = out_biases

        self._n_tracks = out_weights.shape[0]
        self.ids_mask = tf.zeros([self._n_tracks], name="playlist_mask")

    def __call__(self, decoder_outputs):
        _logits = tf.matmul(decoder_outputs, self._out_weights)
        _logits = tf.nn.bias_add(_logits, self._out_biases)

        # apply mask
        _logits = _logits + self.ids_mask

        _sample_ids = tf.cast(tf.argmax(_logits, axis=-1), tf.int32)

        # update mask
        step_ids_mask = tf.sparse_to_dense(_sample_ids, [self._n_tracks], -np.inf)
        self.ids_mask = self.ids_mask + step_ids_mask

        return _sample_ids
```

The code of the inference graph looks like this:

```
self._max_playlist_len = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, ())
self._start_tokens = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None])

sample_fn = InferenceSampler(out_weights, out_biases)
with tf.name_scope("inf_decoder"):
    def _end_fn(sample_ids):
        return tf.equal(sample_ids, PAD_ITEM_ID)

    def _next_inputs_fn(sample_ids):
        return tf.nn.embedding_lookup(
            track_embs,
            sample_ids
        )

    _start_inputs = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(
        track_embs,
        self._start_tokens
    )

    helper = tf.contrib.seq2seq.InferenceHelper(
        sample_fn=sample_fn,
        sample_shape=[],
        sample_dtype=tf.int32,
        start_inputs=_start_inputs,
        end_fn=_end_fn,
        next_inputs_fn=_next_inputs_fn
    )
    decoder = tf.contrib.seq2seq.BasicDecoder(
        rnn_cell,
        helper,
        rnn_cell.zero_state(tf.shape(self._start_tokens)[0], tf.float32),
        output_layer=projection_layer
    )
    outputs, _, _ = tf.contrib.seq2seq.dynamic_decode(
        decoder,
        maximum_iterations=self._max_playlist_len
    )

self.playlists = outputs.sample_id
```

Unfortunately, the results still have duplicated labels. Moreover, when I try to get access to the `sample_fn.ids_mask` I receive an error message: `ValueError: Operation 'inf_decoder/decoder/while/BasicDecoderStep/add_1' has been marked as not fetchable.`

What am I doing wrong? And how legal is to create such `sample_fn`?

Comment: why do you repeat `_sample_ids = tf.cast(tf.argmax(_logits, axis=-1), tf.int32)` inside __call__? you already calculated _sample_ids with the old mask, i think if you calculate that again at the last iteration you will have all -inf inside the mask

Comment: Oops... I will check it once again. But I suppose that it's a problem of copy-pasting to SO.

Comment: So, I rechecked the code, and it's the problem of copy paste. It still doesn't work. I updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after some investigation I found answers to all my questions related to this thread. The main question was: why `self.ids_mask` in `InferenceSampler` does not update? The reason is in the internals of `dynamic_decode`. According to [this answer](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/13616#issuecomment-335894888) in Tensorflow's issue tracker:

> ... only tensors defined inside the loop will be evaluated
>   every loop iteration. All tensors defined outside a loop will be
>   evaluated exactly once.

In my case, `self.ids_mask` is specified outside the loop. That means that I need to re-write `dynamic_decode` to get what I want. The code below is a bit modified version of the initial task, but it does almost the same.

Let's start with a new `dynamic_decode` which should create and update the mask collecting `sample_ids` that have been already predicted. I removed the code which i didn't modify, follow the `initial_mask` and `mask` variables.

New `dynamic_decode`:

````
def dynamic_decode(decoder,
                   output_time_major=False,
                   impute_finished=False,
                   maximum_iterations=None,
                   parallel_iterations=32,
                   swap_memory=False,
                   scope=None):
    ...
        initial_finished, initial_inputs, initial_mask, initial_state = decoder.initialize()
    ...
        def body(time, outputs_ta, state, inputs, finished, sequence_lengths, mask):
            """Internal while_loop body.

            Args:
                time: scalar int32 tensor.
                outputs_ta: structure of TensorArray.
                state: (structure of) state tensors and TensorArrays.
                inputs: (structure of) input tensors.
                finished: bool tensor (keeping track of what's finished).
                sequence_lengths: int32 tensor (keeping track of time of finish).
                mask: SparseTensor to remove already predicted items

            Returns:
                `(time + 1, outputs_ta, next_state, next_inputs, next_finished,
                  next_sequence_lengths, next_mask)`.
            ```
            """
            (next_outputs, decoder_state, next_inputs, next_mask,
             decoder_finished) = decoder.step(time, inputs, state, mask)
            ...
            nest.assert_same_structure(state, decoder_state)
            nest.assert_same_structure(outputs_ta, next_outputs)
            nest.assert_same_structure(inputs, next_inputs)
            nest.assert_same_structure(mask, next_mask)
            ...
            return (time + 1, outputs_ta, next_state, next_inputs, next_finished,
                    next_sequence_lengths, next_mask)

        res = control_flow_ops.while_loop(
            condition,
            body,
            loop_vars=[
                initial_time, initial_outputs_ta, initial_state, initial_inputs,
                initial_finished, initial_sequence_lengths, initial_mask,
            ],
            parallel_iterations=parallel_iterations,
            swap_memory=swap_memory)
    ...
    return final_outputs, final_state, final_sequence_lengths
````

At the next step `mask` should be passed to `Decoder` and `Helper`. Here are the updated versions of `BasicDecoder` and `InferenceHelper`:

`MaskedDecoder`:

```
class MaskedDecoder(BasicDecoder):
    def step(self, time, inputs, state, mask, name=None):
        with ops.name_scope(name, "MaskedDecoderStep", (time, inputs, state, mask)):
            cell_outputs, cell_state = self._cell(inputs, state)
            if self._output_layer is not None:
                cell_outputs = self._output_layer(cell_outputs)
            sample_ids = self._helper.sample(
                time=time,
                outputs=cell_outputs,
                state=cell_state,
                mask=mask)
            (finished, next_inputs, next_state, next_mask) = self._helper.next_inputs(
                time=time,
                outputs=cell_outputs,
                state=cell_state,
                mask=mask,
                sample_ids=sample_ids)
        outputs = BasicDecoderOutput(cell_outputs, sample_ids)
        return (outputs, next_state, next_inputs, next_mask, finished)
```

`MaskedInferenceHelper`:

```
class MaskedInferenceHelper(Helper):
    """A helper to use during inference with a custom sampling function."""

    def __init__(self, norm_track_embs, features, start_sample_ids):
        self._norm_track_embs = norm_track_embs

        self._batch_size = tf.shape(start_sample_ids)[0]
        self._n_tracks = tf.shape(norm_track_embs)[0]

        self._start_sample_ids = start_sample_ids

        self._sample_shape = tf.TensorShape([])
        self._sample_dtype = tf.int32

        self._features = features

    def _get_sparse_mask(self, sample_ids):
        _mask_shape = tf.convert_to_tensor([
            tf.cast(self._batch_size, dtype=tf.int64),
            tf.cast(self._n_tracks, dtype=tf.int64)
        ])

        _st_rows = tf.range(0, self._batch_size)
        _st_cols = sample_ids

        _st_indices = tf.cast(tf.stack([_st_rows, _st_cols], axis=1), dtype=tf.int64)
        _st_values = tf.fill([self._batch_size], np.inf)

        return tf.SparseTensor(_st_indices, _st_values, _mask_shape)

    ...

    def initialize(self, name=None):
        finished = tf.tile([False], [self._batch_size])
        start_embs = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(self._norm_track_embs, self._start_sample_ids)
        start_inputs = tf.concat([start_embs, self._features], axis=1)
        mask = self._get_sparse_mask(self._start_sample_ids)
        return finished, start_inputs, mask

    def sample(self, time, outputs, state, mask, name=None):
        del time, state  # unused by sample

        outputs = tf.nn.l2_normalize(outputs, axis=-1)
        cos_sims = tf.matmul(outputs, self._norm_track_embs, transpose_b=True)
        cos_sims = cos_sims - tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense(mask)
        sample_ids = tf.cast(tf.argmax(cos_sims, axis=-1), tf.int32)

        return sample_ids

    def next_inputs(self, time, outputs, state, sample_ids, mask, name=None):
        del time, outputs  # unused by next_inputs
        finished = tf.tile([False], [self._batch_size])
        next_embs = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(self._norm_track_embs, sample_ids)
        next_inputs = tf.concat([next_embs, self._features], axis=1)
        next_mask = tf.sparse_add(mask, self._get_sparse_mask(sample_ids))

        return finished, next_inputs, state, next_mask
```

So, now I can generate inferences without repetition of already predicted items.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to overcome the problem, I updated the inference in such a way that at each RNN step I output the vector of embeddings instead of `item_id`. After the inference is finished, I convert embeddings to `item_ids`.

First of all, this solution minimizes the number of operations. Secondly, since I use LSTM/GRU cells, they minimize the probability to observe two absolutely similar outputs on different steps of RNN's inference.

The new code looks like this:

```
with tf.name_scope("inf_decoder"):
    def _sample_fn(decoder_outputs):
        return decoder_outputs

    def _end_fn(sample_ids):
        # infinite
        return tf.tile([False], [n_seeds])

    _start_inputs = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(
        track_embs,
        self._seed_items
    )

    helper = tf.contrib.seq2seq.InferenceHelper(
        sample_fn=_sample_fn,
        sample_shape=[self.emb_size],
        sample_dtype=tf.float32,
        start_inputs=_start_inputs,
        end_fn=_end_fn,
    )
    decoder = tf.contrib.seq2seq.BasicDecoder(
        rnn_cell,
        helper,
        rnn_cell.zero_state(n_seeds, tf.float32),
        output_layer=projection_layer
    )
    outputs, _, _ = tf.contrib.seq2seq.dynamic_decode(
        decoder,
        maximum_iterations=self._max_playlist_len
    )

flat_rnn_output = tf.reshape(outputs.rnn_output, [-1, self.emb_size])
flat_logits = tf.matmul(flat_rnn_output, out_weights, transpose_b=True)
flat_logits = tf.nn.bias_add(flat_logits, out_biases)

item_ids = tf.cast(tf.argmax(flat_logits, axis=-1), tf.int32)
playlists = tf.reshape(item_ids, [n_seeds, -1])

self.playlists = playlists
```